# Visual Studio is keeping a handle open after stopping the debugger

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I keep getting the following error in MS Visual Stdio:

> Unable to copy file "obj\Debug[Program].exe" to "bin\Debug[Program].exe". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug[Program].exe' because it is being used by another process.

This happens randomly after I close and/or stop the debugger. The program is closed, but VS keeps a couple handles open to the program.

[image: Handles opened]

The only way I've found to be able to re-debug is to close Visual Studio, and reopen it, which is very annoying.

Any idea why this is happening, and how I can run the debugger again without first closing it?

This has happened in 2013 Ultimate, and 2015 Ultimate.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this for any specific code or for any code that you are executing ?

Comment: It's happening with a specific project. I just tried getting it to happen on a smaller project to no avail. But not sure if that means it's my project, or if it's just being sporadic.

Comment: can you post the code where you are being stucked ?

Comment: I would, but it's a couple thousand lines, between multiple files (Not including the automatic code), and no breakpoint is ever triggered, so it's not like it is a specific area of code. And as I just mentioned, it's not happening with a smaller project.

Comment: Okay, Is your code using any streams that is opened even after the debugger ends? any interop object that still is opened ? any third party dlls that is using the stream ?

Comment: No, and all one thread, and all C# code except for what MS includes. It's basically Notepad (but with fewer menu items, thought it does have couple extra things, like print preview).

Comment: you can try right-clicking on the project from the Solution Explorer, and clicking on "Unload Project". Then Reload the project. However this is just a workaround that will stop you needed to close VS, it's not a fix.

Comment: @David, this time its really complicated to figure out the problem. This kind of situation happens generally, when streams are not freed before exiting the application or, some of the background thread is working without any appearance. Try to debug/break the debugger when this happens, also prefer Parallel stacks windows to watch where the application hangs ?

Comment: This is an environmental problem, invariably caused by anti-malware.  Which gets *way* too excited when it sees an .exe file appear from no-where.  You need to make an exclusion for your project directories.  If it is Avast then get rid of it completely.

Comment: @RohitPrakash, if I have a linear application, what could possibly be getting stuck?

Comment: @David, as Mr. Hans said, its a environmental problem. He is always on the point.

Comment: @HansPassant, have you seen it do that only on occasion, and never bother to ask about it? Using AVG latest.

Comment: I've seen way too many programmers struggle with this problem, not much point in asking about it.  Anti-malware is a cure that's worse than the disease on a programmer's machine.  It was made to keep your mom's machine running.  MSBuild has counter-measures to work around it by trying to copy the file up to ten times and sleeping for a bit in between attempts.  But that of course still won't work when the anti-malware won't give up soon enough.  Nobody ever has a problem with Microsoft's Defender.

Comment: @HansPassant, told the AVG resident shield to ignore that folder, seemed to be working, but just got the same issue again. Expect now it says "The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open."

Comment: @David I have a solution, I have added it below.  Basically "Any CPU" settings change from build to build, but most developers forget their target builds of x86 and x64 were just "copying settings" from "Any CPU" templates, which change very build.  That's all.  I run through the steps below to fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am going to propose a new solution, that permanently fixes it.  I have always done this, when experiencing "Debugger" issues that occur mostly when moving to a new Visual Studio with an old Solution, so your mileage may vary.

If, switching back to AnyCPU configuration allows you to debug again, then I believe the following steps will fix it.

1. Go into "Configuration Manager", change "Active solution platform:" to Any CPU, click the down Arrow again, and select "Edit...", delete ANY custom entries here, even if it is just x86 and x64.
2. In the same Window, enter the Platform under your Project and repeat Step 1.  Remove all entries but AnyCPU.
3. Close Configuration Manager.
4. Go to "Build" menu and click "Clean Solution".
5. Restart Visual Studio 2015 CTP 5 as Administrator. Open your solution.  Use "Any CPU" for one build, Release or Debug, and then close back out of it. Just verify you are able to basically use the "Any CPU" target still.
6. Minimize Visual Studio, go into your solution and clean out all your Bins/Release and Debugs, including any x86/x64 Release/Debug folders if they are still present.
7. Maximize Visual Studio, enter Configuration Manager, rebuild your platform targets (x86/x64) copying settings from the verified working: "Any CPU".
8. Start happily working again!

The error is caused by incorrect, out of date, or corrupted "Target Platform" settings saved in the Solution / Project.  You can repeat the steps above, again removing the "Any CPU" setting under the Project Solutions, as it can also have bad juju cached in there.  Adding it again with the terms "Any CPU" settings copy settings "Empty Settings" may also fix the issue.  You then want to remove everything else, and re-add it as x86/x64 using the new Any CPU settings.

Decided to make a How-To with illustrations on my [blog/site](http://www.bytemedev.com/how-to-fix-visual-studio-error-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-another-process/).

Now if you only have "Any CPU" as your configuration as an issue, there are three things that can cause this.  "Any CPU" setting that needs refreshing, open stream can equal open handles, or possibly a StackOverflow exception, just hasn't overflowed yet.

If this is occurring with "Any CPU" and you have no other target solutions, you may first want try this.  Add one new platform target, x86/x64, Copy settings from Any CPU is fine.  This will allow you to remove Any CPU, from the Configuration Manager and the Solution.  You can then Add a new solution, called Any CPU, with "empty settings" as the setting option.  Then remove x86/x64.  This forces a refresh of the Any CPU configuration inside your project.  Try having a build or two.

If it is still occurring, you more than likely need to revisit your code if it is occurring with "Any CPU".  This could be a bad streaming/unclosed stream issue, a poor COM call that is hung in system etc.  Whenever I am experimenting with Unmanaged code, or system processes, I try and handle application hangs and StackOverflows.  Which may be occurring as mentioned previously.

```
Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException +=
        new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);

Application.ThreadException +=
        new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);

static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Exception ex = (Exception)e.ExceptionObject;

        MessageBox.Show("Congratulations, you have broken this program like no other user before you!\n\n" +
              "Exception : " + ex.Message + "\n\n" + "Stack : " + ex.StackTrace,
              "Ridonculous Exception Occurred", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
    }
    finally
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}

static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This is a StackOverflow Exception!\n\n" +
              "Exception : " + e.Exception.Message + "\n\n" + "Stack : " + e.Exception.StackTrace,
              "Ridonculous StackOverflow Exception Occurred", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
    }
    finally
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

Source: http://tech.pro/tutorial/668/csharp-tutorial-dealing-with-unhandled-exceptions

***Alternatively: If you have multi-Visual Studio installs, or even preview Vstudios installed, you may break JIT unknowingly by switching back and forth or running Updates.  The latest version(s) of Visual Studio actually informs you of JIT errors (potential or not) and advises you to repair the IDE.***
[image: Tools -> Options]

[image: How To Repair]

[image: How To Repair 2]

Anything else, would be beyond my level of knowledge.  Best of luck to you!

Comment: Sadly, the only target platform I have is Any CPU.

Comment: This issue occurs on your solution using only "Any CPU"?  This project was not started with this Visual Studio version was it?

Comment: ^ Appending a plan B and plan C.

Comment: Tried B and C, still no go. Appreciate all the input though.

Comment: @David I may have reproduced your issue, it was specifically having Visual Studio 2013 on my laptop and Visual Studio 2015.

I opened the solution in 2013, only to realize I needed to add 4.5.2 framework to Visual Studio 2013 after I was forced to lower my target assembly coming from Visual Studio 2015, to framework 4.5 (not 4.5.1) to open the solution.  Issues occurred immediately after installing patches and the additional framework to VS2013. I even had the error (posted above) in 2015 now being displayed.  It appears they do not necessarily play well together.

Comment: Argghh, still not working. I have noticed that it tends to happen when I debug, stop, modify, and recompile / debug. However, if I make the changes while in debug mode, it doesn't break. Only if the changes are made between the debugging sessions. Nonetheless, though it hasn't solved my particular issue, you've put forth 4 solid ideas, so I'm still going to mark this as the answer, and leave mine as a secondary solution.

Comment: Hmm, just saw the window that says to repair. I repaired without looking at that, but it's still saying repair. Guess I'll do that again in a bit with hopes it works.

Comment: I think it is primarily a conflict between running 2015 and 2013 on the same system.  I admit though once it starts triggering with "Any CPU" nothing seems to get rid of it.  The repair worked, but rather risk it occurring again, I removed all VS2015, since I can't reproduce the issue on any of my systems with just 2013, only when 2015 is installed.

Furthermore, as a last ditched effort, you can create a new project... copying in each class and then "copy pasta" the code into solution, settings, designer.resx etc.

Comment: I've only got 2015 installed on this OS. 2013 is on the other partition.

Comment: Have you opened / saved your solution in 2015 as well as 2013?  If that's the case, the problem may still lie inside of the solution.  Some configuration is bad, or still using 2015s settings or vice versa.  I just tried removing the Debug and Release profiles, then rebuilding them with empty settings.  Then configuring them in Project properties to include Debug/Trace for Debug, and just Trace for release.  As far as I can tell there was no harm done (2 days now.)  Be sure to do it inside the Project Solution under configuration manager, i.e. in Configuration Manager, under Configuration.

Comment: I'd say yes, since the original project was converted, but I just finished up with another one which was giving me the same issue, and that one was done fully in 2015.

Comment: i.e. in Configuration Manager, under Configuration for the project* not Visual Studio (Active.)

Answer (score 2):

RagingCain has some excellent solutions. If all else fails, the following will:

1. Use Process Explorer to close the handles to the file.
2. Manually Delete the .exe file

After that, it should recompile.

Answer (score 1):

Project properties - Disable the Visual Studio Hosting process.

Worked for me.